# How do I add a ID to my textbox or dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

In my view I have textbox and dropdown menu , I am trying to add an Class so that I can apply bootstrap themes to my fields. This is my code:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID)
        </div>
    </div>
```

How do I declare class to this `class="from-controller"` I tried this `@Html.DropDownList("ID", new {class="test"})` but I get an error. Can anyone tell me why.

Comment: You forgot `@` sign before class `@Html.DropDownList("ID", new { @class="test"})` like you did with the label.

Comment: @Zabavsky this is what i did `@Html.DropDownList("ID", String.Empty, new { @class="test"})` i get error as `Represents text as a serious of unicode characters`

Comment: It also says `'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<projectname>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>, string)' has some invalid arguments `

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of the [DropDownList Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, so your dropdown has to look like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ID", new SelectList(Model.CollectionOfIds, "DataValueField", "DataTextField"),
    new { @class= "from-controller" })
```

Answer (score 0):

First parameter is name not an ID. If you want to specify an id you have to do it same way as specifying a class.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlName", new SelectList(Model.Items, "Key", "Value"), "Please select", new { @class = "className", @id="yourId" })
```

new SelectList(Model.Items, "Key", "Value") will work for

```
Dictionary<int, string>
```

type

Answer (score 0):

**First :**

class is a reserved keyword of c# language. When you want use a reserved keyword like variable name in C# you should put the **@** sign before variable name to the compiler ignore the fact that it's also a keyword.

in your case your must add **@** before class keyword

```
new {@class="test"})
```

**Second :**

There are not definition for Html.DropDownList(string, string) or Html.DropDownList(string, string, object)

the second parameter must be an IEnumerable

If you want set an empty list (I don't undersant why you set a String.Empy value) use Enumerable.Empty()

```
@Html.DropDownList("ID", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>())
```